# How to handle dot symbol in Excel Column names while using excel as a database

Tags: sql, excel, database

While using Excel as database I am getting an error 'Invalid bracketing of name '[No. of days late]'.I am thinking the dot symbol in the column name [No. of days late] is making the issue.

Query used : SELECT [Item Code],[No. of days late so far] FROM [SheetName$]

Please advise me how to handle this issue.

Many thanks

Comment: Your SQL is missing a comma between the column names, no? Is your SO question pasted from the broekn code or re-typed/contains typos?

Comment: Sorry Caius  it's a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct; the driver doesn't like the `.` in your column name. Turns out, we can get it to tell us the answer too:

[image]

By making the driver select everything into a datatable and having a look at what it did (point to the datatable in the debugger, click the magnifying glass to open the visualizer), we can see that `.` in column names are converted to `#` - if you craft your column names to the same rule, it works